# Setting switch() to not break after a matched case and instead continuing on to all matched cases

Tags: php, switch-statement, control-structure

I'm really just curious about this, and I don't plan on implementing it, but I do think it would be a cool control structure to use should the appropriate conditions arise.

I have an array of booleans that represent which types of data a user is trying to see and then I have an object of booleans saying if a user has permission to see that data or not.

Instead of a list of if statements saying `if(permission and display){show this type}`, I thought I would instead just use a switch(true) and actually write the same amount of code but formatted a bit nicer, if only I could get a switch statement to `continue;` .. that would have been cool.

```
switch(true){
    case ($processPermissions->history->view) && ($display['history'] !== false):
        $application['history'] = $this->getHistory();
        continue;

    case ($processPermissions->notepad->view) && ($display['notepad'] !== false):
        $application['notepad'] = $this->notepad('get');
        continue;

    case ($processPermissions->documents->view) && ($display['documents'] !== false):
        $application['documents'] = $this->documents('get');
        continue;

    case ($processPermissions->accounting->view) && ($display['accounting'] !== false):
        $application['accounting'] = $this->accounting('get');
        continue;

    case ($processPermissions->inspections->view) && ($display['inspections'] !== false):
        $application['inspections'] = $this->inspections('get');
        continue;

    case ($processPermissions->approvals->view) && ($display['approvals'] !== false):
        $application['approvals'] = $this->approvals('get');
        continue;
}
```

In reality, I'm just going to create an array and loop through that since the code is identical for each case.

..But I'm very curious about how I would be able to get this to work, if I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a lot of pointless repetition, when you could have something like

```
$stuff_to_check = array('history', 'notepad', 'documents', 'accounting', etc....)
foreach($stuff_to_check as $thing) {
   if ($processPermissions->$thing->view && ($display[$thing] !== false))
       $applications[$thing] = $this->document('get');
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I said I was going to do in the last sentence of the post :P This is all curiosity

Answer (score 0):

It's already supported - just don't include the `break` statement and every `case` block after the one that matched will be executed as well, until a `break` is encountered.

Also, the `continue` statement is already supported in `switch` blocks in PHP, but its behaviour is similar to `break`.

See the documentation for [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) for more details.

```
$value = 2;
switch ($value) {
    case 0:
        // not executed
    case 1:
        // not executed
    case 2:
        // executed
    case 'whatever':
        // executed
        break;
    case 'foo':
        // not executed
        break;
    default:
        // not executed
}
```

See the documentation for [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) for more details.

Comment: Indeed, that's a thing, but if you have $permission for the first case and don't break, yet no permissions for the second case, it will still continue even if case returns false. `switch(true){case true: echo "this should work!"; case false: echo "This shouldn't, but it will!"; break; }`

Comment: Ah, got you - so literally just a way to write `if` statements with more code? Not sure I agree that it would be cool, but sure the world would be a boring place if we all saw it the same way :)

Comment: Maybe someday I'll use it in a code obfuscation contest, or to make co-workers scratch their head. There's probably no valid use for it, honestly, but it's been a lingering thought for at least an hour and that's the threshold for me asking questions

Comment: If it's confusing you want, how about this intead of `if`s ;) `$processPermissions->history->view && !$display['history'] && $application['history'] = $this->getHistory();`

Comment: If I wanted confusing I would do the following. WARNING: NSFW, I'm kinda embarrassingly good at this.... `!(($a = ${1} = $processPermissions->history->view) &&!$$a = !$display['history'] &&$$a) ?: $application['history'] = $this->getHistory();` and yes it works 100% how it's intended. ahh that was too much fun, thanks for the unintended challenge

Comment: Oh, the challenge was intended ;) Very nice - my eyes are bleeding now lol